# Eclipse, Git, show diff branch to master without merges from master

Tags: git, eclipse, branch

I am using eclipse 2020-06. I have a feature branch with some merges from master. I want to see my changes in the feature branch without those changes from the merges. Just what have I done in this branch. When I compare via history commits, the merges are always included.

Answer (score 0):

I think then you have to compare the last commit from the feature branch with the last master's commit that you merged into your feature branch.